# Change url parameters to slashes

Tags: javascript, php, url

I have two questions

(1) I would like to know if it is possible to change this URL example.co.uk/list?jobs=2 to example.co.uk/list/jobs/2 using php or javascript.

(2) How can I hide a specific text based on the logged in user id.

Comment: for url rewrite use .htaccess

Comment: search google by friendly url

Comment: can you explain second one more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this in your .htaccess for rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
# add this following cond if the Rewrite rule rewrites css, js etc. files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^list/jobs/([0-9]+)$ list.php?jobs=$1 [L,NC]
```

Your second problem:

when you are showing the post to the user you should have check if current user is the owner of this post if yes then show delete button with post if not then do not show delete button with post.

Example:

```
$posts = array(); // get all posts from database

$current_user = "";// get current user


foreach($posts as $p ){

  echo "title: ". $p['title']." post Data :".$p['post_data'];
  if($p['user'] == $current_user ){
    echo "<input type='button' value='delete'> ";      
   }
}
```

Be smart do not use javascript hide/show for this purpose. any one can delete your post by inspect your html in browser.

Comment: Thank you, i have found a solution to the second question.

Comment: @user3159565: I have updated my answer for second one. You can check it.